# Dagger 2 subclass with a more specific dependency than the parent class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm working on a object hierarchy like this:

```
class Foo extends View
{
    @Inject BaseDependency dep;

    Foo() // Default android view constructors
    {
        injectDependencies();
    }

    protected void injectDependencies()
    {
        getApp().getFooComponent().inject(this);
    }
}


class ExtraBaseDependency extends BaseDependency
{
    @Inject
    ExtraBaseDependency() {}
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    @Inject ExtraBaseDependency dep;

    @Override
    protected void injectDependencies()
    {
        getApp().getBarComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want in my more specific 'Bar' subclass the 'ExtraBaseDependency' with more methods on it and I ALSO, want to provide Foo with the same object as I'm collecting data from the whole hierarchy to be used in Bar.

I thought that, by overriding injectDependencies() and NOT calling super, that I could provide both my subclass AND its parent the dependency they need, but only ONE of them to share but Bar would get the more specific interface of the object so it can do its job.

The behavior I'm seeing is that while it does compile and run, I'm seeing ExtraBaseDependency being constructed twice.

My FooComponent and BarComponents have different scopes and different modules that are both separate. I am unsure as to why I'm not getting the same instance in the base class as the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your fields will continue to exist; [fields are not polymorphic in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7794621/1426891). Foo can't access `Bar.dep`, but Bar can access `Foo.dep` via `super.dep`.

Dagger will automatically inject the supertype fields and methods of any type you inject,
 so if you call `inject(Bar)` Dagger will inject Foo's fields as well as Bar's. (Per [a note about covariance](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#a-note-about-covariance), you do have to be careful not to call `inject(Foo)`, as that will only inject Foo's fields even if you pass in a Bar instance at runtime. [See more here, but injecting without explicitly calling `super` is the right thing to do anyway.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43022590/1426891))

A few solutions:

- *Let it be.* Foo requires a BaseDependency, Bar requires an ExtraBaseDependency, and Foo might even keep that dependency package-private so Bar has no access to Foo's field (which might be important if the field is stateful or if multiple threads are involved). If you consider each class responsible for declaring its own dependencies, this is working as intended, albeit wastefully.
- *Scope the dependency if it should be scoped.* If BaseDependency and ExtraBaseDependency are consistent across the lifetime of their component, you can mark it with a scope (e.g. `@Singleton` or `@Reusable`) to cut down on the dependencies' recreation, or just save and return an instance in a `@Module` if it's more appropriate to manage the singleton instance yourself. This isn't a good general-purpose solution, but if this is lingering work anyway, then you can solve this problem with it too.
- *Switch to constructor parameters if possible (which it isn't, for your case).* If Bar extends Foo, Bar can have an `@Inject`-annotated constructor, which explicitly calls Foo's constructor with the specific dependencies you request. Of course, for Android Views, you'll need members injection; this is an option for your other cases, or for other readers.
- *Drop the `@Inject` annotation from Foo.dep.* Foo.dep's injection evidently depends on its subclass, and fields are not polymorphic, so letting Foo declare its `@Inject`-annotated field simply isn't safe for the way you're using it.
- *Refactor Foo into an abstract base class.* This also isn't a general solution for everything, but you can clear up class hierarchy woes by designing Foo for subclassing and exposing a BasicFoo or DefaultFoo implementation. This would make it a subclass responsibility to populate Foo.dep, which may be easier to reason about in your class hierarchy anyway.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I haven't tried making the class abstract, but I feel like this should be able to work.
 I can't keep it the way it is because the dependency is a 'mediator' type object and needs to be the same for the class and all its super classes.
The dependency is scoped with a custom scope.
If I drop the @Inject from the base class, how will it get its dependency?

I haven't tried making the class a base class but that may work. I need to look into that some more. Would you just have an abstract getter for the BaseDependency?

Comment: Digging through the MembersInjectors, it looks like Dagger is choosing to use two different providers to inject Foo and Bar. It seems like having an abstract class may be the only way to go.